# How to Authenticate a REST Call to the Firebase Auth REST API

Tags: firebase, rest, firebase-authentication

I want to build a client app that Signs up with an email/password in my Firebase project, I was able to do it, but I'm concerned about the fact that I can do it without any authentication. Is there any way to apply authentication to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Auth REST API doesn't have any authentication.  It's a public API that's also used by the Firebase SDKs that can be included in any app.  The point of the API is the allow users to authenticate themselves without additional permissions.  You control the types of auth allowed in your app using the Firebase console.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info, I was wondering if there's some documentation that supports this, sorry I don't mean to contradict/deny your answer, I just want to make sure and pass this information to my PM.

Comment: Read the documentation for the API - you'll see no mention of what you're asking about.  Seems to me that, if the API doesn't document it, it's not supported. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth

Comment: Thanks, that's all I needed.